# Who wins a flush draw when the high card is a community card?

Tags: texas-hold-em

Player 1:  `7d 8d`

Player 2:  `9d Jd`

Board:  `Qc Kd 4h 5d Ad`

Both players have a diamond flush, but I'm curious, does player 2 win with a higher diamond or do they split the pot since the flush high card is an Ace?

Comment: Player 2 wins Ad Kd Jd 9d 5d is the best hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hand is made by using your hole cards and the five cards in the middle to make the best possible five card hand. All 5 cards are taken into consideration. Therefore, in this case, player 2 will win.